# The syntax and OnItemSelectedListener args

Tags: android

I use Eclipse  ADT build:v21.1.0-569685, the Case One is an sample code from website, but it cause the error
"The type new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener(){} must implement the inherited abstract method AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener.onNothingSelected(AdapterView)"

so I have to use the Case Two, but sometimes the Case One is OK, what happened? Thanks!

**Case One**

```
private void InitSpinner(){
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter1 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,
            nameList.toArray(new String[nameList.size()]));
    adapter1.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinnerFolder.setAdapter(adapter1); 
    spinnerFolder.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                    "cw", 2000).show();

        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    }); 
}
```

**Case Two**

```
private void InitSpinner(){
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter1 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,
            nameList.toArray(new String[nameList.size()]));
    adapter1.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinnerFolder.setAdapter(adapter1); 
    spinnerFolder.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                int arg2, long arg3) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                    "cw", 2000).show();

        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    }); 
}
```

Comment: hmm.. In both cases the codes you mentioned are same.. Can you point what difference you made in case 2

Comment: Only the arg's name is different, the One is  public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent)... the Two is public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0)..., so I'm very surprising why the system don't think the case One implement the inherited abstract method AdapterView. Must the arg's name in subclasses be the same with abstract method ?

Comment: And more,maybe the different version Android ADK define  different args for new OnItemSelectedListener(), is it right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*@Paul*

***Does the arguments name must be same?***

No, the arguments name need not be same. And as such both codes are exactly identical and will work in same fashion.

***Why I get***

```
 The type new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener(){} must implement the inherited abstract method AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener.onNothingSelected(AdapterView)
```

***error?***

I guess you must have copied that part of code from your other project's or must have copied directly from internet through some site. In here, You have copied the correct syntax, but have not done right imports for the same....

Try..

**Ctrl+Shift+O**   to organise all the essential import required...

Hope it helps.....

Comment: Thanks. You are right. I lost import android.view.View; , but I'm very surprised the Quick Fixes Avaiable popup menu for the args View view don't dispaly the item Import ... , why?

Comment: Thanks. You are right. I lost import android.view.View , but I'm very surprised the 7 Quick Fixes Available popup menu for the args View view don't dispaly the suggestion item Import  android.view.View , why?

Comment: Well, no proper answer for this, maybe eclipse wasn't smart enough to do so on its own...